# CentOS7.6：No manual entry for ANY COMMAND

Tags: linux, centos7

> my system is CentOS7.6

I can't use man to search anyting

```
$ man pthread_create
No manual entry for pthread_create
$ man bind
No manual entry for bind
$ man man
No manual entry for man
$ man ls
No manual entry for ls
```

I have tried update,man still not working

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.njupt.edu.cn
No packages marked for update
```

```
# yum install man-pages
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.njupt.edu.cn
Package man-pages-3.53-5.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

how can I get `man` back to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is environment value

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/share/man
```

the environment value link to gcc,which is wrong

```
yum reinstall man-pages
```

check man install path

```
# whereis man
man: /usr/bin/man /usr/share/man /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/man.1p.gz
```

add it into your environment value

```
export MANPATH=/usr/share/man
```

the problem will be fixed

---

last thing you need to do is add it into `~/.bashrc`

```
MANPATH=/usr/share/man
```

or `/etc/bashrc`

```
export MANPATH=/usr/share/man
```

BE CAREFUL when you edit config-file, always backup before editing